# How To convert [__NSArrayI integerValue] to integer value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinteger

This the line i have using to convert the object to integer values,Inside For Loop I have Placed This code

```
   NSInteger tag=[[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"category"] integerValue];
```

Inside arrFullSubCategory:

```
(
        {
        category = 35;
        image = "images/Hatchback.jpg";
        name = Hatchback;
        parent = 20;
    },
        {
        category = 36;
        image = "images/Sedan.jpg";
        name = Sedan;
        parent = 20;
    },
        {
        category = 37;
        image = "images/SUV.jpg";
        name = SUV;
        parent = 20;
    }
)
```

Exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff4ba58f930'
```

Comment: Do something Like this :

[[[arrFullSubCategory objectatindex:i] valueForKey:@"category"] integerValue];

Comment: Which `category` do you expect to get, - 35, 36, or 37?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight everything...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i got answer.

Comment: @KishoreKumar If you want everything, how would 35, 36, and 37 fit in a single `NSInteger`?

Comment: @Mehul i don't how i was forget this any way thanks.....

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so i have done that inside for loop

Comment: @KishoreKumar Now that's your answer then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89259/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-dasblinkenlight).

Comment: @KishoreKumar, Good luck, keep coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrFullSubCategory` is an array and you should reach it's elements first. Than you will have `NSDictionary` objects. After that you can access your `category` element. So I think your code should be like that:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < arrFullSubCategory.count; ++i) {
    NSInteger tag=[[[arrFullSubCategory objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"] integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of the error:

The error means you have an *array*, and arrays don't respond to `integerValue`.

Your variable `arrFullSubCategory` references an array (of 3 elements), and each element is a dictionary. If you call `valueForKey:` on an array of dictionaries then the key lookup is performed for each dictionary and an array is constructed for the results. In your case the result (using literal syntax) is the array:

```
@[ @35, @36, @37 ]
```

Whether this array is directly useful to you, or whether you should access the array one element at a time - using a loop or method which calls a block per element, etc. - will depend on what your goal is.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside for loop I hope this help you

```
NSInteger tag=[[[arrFullSubCategory objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have array of dictionary, So you use it given below code

```
[[[arrFullSubCategory objectAtIndex:] objectForKey:@"category"] integerValue]
```